# Getting error while importing downloaded github project (scala)?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, package, sbt

So I'm pretty new at scala. I'm trying to use this library in my other project: https://www.github.com/desmondyeung/scala-hashing

I downloaded it, and looked up a guide on how to use downloaded projects (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch18s11.html), and it said to make a build.scala and then put some such in it. The way I've tried to do that is this:

```
import sbt._
object MyBuild extends Build {
lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")) dependsOn(xxHash)
lazy val xxHash = RootProject(uri("file:///Users/[other stuff]/documents/GitHub/scala-hashing-master/project"))
}
```

And that's all that's in that build.scala file. It's under the project folder.

I tried to run it using some simple test code:

```
import xxHash._
object hashtest {
  def main(): Unit = {
  println(XxHash.com.desmondyeung.hashing.Xxhash64.hashByteArray(Array[Byte](xs = 123), seed = 0))
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error, it says "not found: object xxHash". I must be missing something, because the guide doesn't tell me how to reference it I don't think? I tried just using `import com.desmondyeung.hashing.XxHash64` but it didn't work either, saying `object desmondyeung is not a member of package com`

I googled that, and it said to try putting `_root_` before .com, but that did not work.

Comment: Why not just using the published library from **Maven**? BTW, it seems that the library hasn't been updated in 2 years, that may be a good reason to search for another one.

Comment: Honestly, because I have no idea how to use a maven package lol. Also, it's the only one I could find on github that uses the necessary hashing algorithm that's in scala.

Comment: The `README` says how to add it - `libraryDependencies += "com.desmondyeung.hashing" %% "scala-hashing" % "0.1.0"` it may be good to do a basic tutorial in **Scala** and **sbt** before-

Comment: Yeah but even when I added that line to build.sbt it still told me that it wasn't a member of com. From what I'm googling, do I need to build the github package and put the resulting jar into my project somehow? I don't even know what to google hahaha

Comment: The build tool will download the jar and put it in the classpath for you. Where are you seeing that error? In an IDE? Maybe you need to reimport the project. In the **sbt** console? Did try running `clean;cleanFiles;reload` first and then `compile`. - The othe thing is that what the hell is `build.scala`? Again, I would just stop there and do a basic tutorial that shows you how to use **sbt**. - Also, it seems you are not importing the classes the way it is intended, did you read the `README`?

Comment: This is how your code should look like: https://github.com/BalmungSan/demo-scala-hashing

Comment: Ah thank you so much! I figured out the problem as a result! my work laptop has some weird proxy and when I tried to rebuild your project from the sbt menu, I finally saw that I was having a proxy error preventing me from downloading it!  Gonna go upvote like 5 of your answers as a thanks

Comment: I think ancient versions of sbt used `build.scala`, but that gives an idea of how old the library is (it might be a minor miracle if it's published for 2.13...).